# shut down restart command

Tags: shutdown

I have a dual boot setup with windows and ubuntu 14.04 LTS. When I start my desktop, and start ubuntu, it starts great. Problem is, the drop down menu that was in the top right hand corner of the desktop is missing. I can't find any options to shut down, or restart. My only option is to use the power button on the computer to shut it down. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! please also specify your Ubuntu desktop environment. For starters you can try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure what's wrong with your system but for now you can also shutdown your system within the terminal by typing `sudo shutdown -hP now` or reboot with the command `sudo shutdown -r now`!
for more infos/options have a look at `shutdown --help`.